# Creating userDecision based off the third index within an array

Tags: swift, xcode

```
    func Decision() {
    if ArrowType.index(ArrowType.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) == "<" {
        UserChoice = "L"
    } else if {ArrowType.index(ArrowType.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) == ">"           
        UserChoice = "R"
    }
}
```

Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.Index' and 'String'

Comment: @RajeshKumarR how do you intend to init a `String` with a `String.Index`? Perhaps you meant `ArrowType[ArrowType.index(ArrowType.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

ArrowType.index(ArrowType.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) will return index not value. Use below code to get the value on that index:

```
ArrowType[ArrowType.index(ArrowType.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)]
```

Comment: Asif, thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it greatly!!